# Migrate user authentication to Firebase Auth

Tags: authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication, bcrypt

I'm a developer at a company that has an application that is built with PHP and MySQL. We have about 300 users that have their passwords hashed with bcrypt and stored in the users table. We're looking to rebuild the application with Angular and Firebase.

My question is, how to I migrate these users over Firebase and use Firebase Auth. It's easy to migrate the profile info over, but I want to be sure that the user can still use the same email/password when they login to the new application.

Here are some approaches that I've thought of. All of these are terrible in my opinion.

A) Create a custom auth system that uses bcrypt, and then just copy the hash over. This isn't what I want because I don't want to maintain a custom auth solution.

B) Every time a user logs into the old system, grab their password from the login field, store it in plaintext, then manually create each user in Firebase with their email/password. This would require 100% of users to login before we switch to the new app. That is unlikely. Also this is obviously a breach of privacy. I'm sure it breaks some sort of law or standard. But it works and it's a last resort option.

C) Every time the user logs in to the old system, send the email/password in plaintext to a script that auto-creates a new Firebase user with the same user/email. This would require 100% of users to login before we switch to the new app. That is unlikely. It's also harder to build than option B.

None of theses options look very good. They all have downsides. Is there a better option? If not, between B and C, which is most legal/ethical? Option B tempts me because it's super simple, but I don't want to break any laws or lose the trust of my companies clients.

Comment: Here is a guide about how to import user to firebase Auth from many different kind of hash mechanism. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/import-users

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[From Firebase Authentication team]

Firebase has a better solution. Firebase Authentication service has the capability to batch import password ***hashes*** of your existing users, for well known hash algorithms (hmac-sha256, bcrypt, scrypt etc.). End users just sign with their existing passwords, and your app will receive a Firebase token containing the same user_id you uploaded. None of the option A/B/C is needed.

[Update 11/19] The [Firebase command line tool](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) 3.2.0 supports importing bcrypt hashed passwords to Firebase Authentication service.

Comment: That's great. Is there an email newsletter that I can get on that would announce this when it comes out? Also, roughly how long are we talking? One month? One year? One decade?

Comment: Is there any way to get on some sort of beta program for this feature?

Comment: Firebase release notes can be found at https://firebase.google.com/support/releases.

Comment: To try the feature now, you can file a feature request at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/, and we will get back to you with instructions.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclosure**: I work at Auth0.

**Disclaimer**: If you really set your mind on using Firebase from a practical point of view this might not help you as it focuses on what Auth0 provides to solve problems similar to the one you described. **However, from a theoretical point of view this might help you so I deemed it worthwhile to share.**

---

Enough with the legal stuff...

Check this guide for a fully detailed view on how [Auth0 supports migrating users from your custom store to a hosted one](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/migrating).

> ... automatic migration of users to Auth0 from a custom database connection. This feature adds your users to the Auth0 database one-at-a-time as each logs in and avoids asking your users to reset their passwords all at the same time.

The approach would be similar to your option C, but the only thing that would need to stay from the old system would be the database. Everyone would start using the new application and the login would happen transparently for the users. Depending on the API's made available by Firebase, you could most likely implement something similar and that would be my recommendation.

**Additionally, you should not even consider any process that includes manual steps and has to deal with plain text passwords.**

---

<sub>A final note, excellent decision on rebuilding your app to use an external authentication service, even if it's not Auth0. :)</sub>

<sub>Authentication is a hard problem and wish more application developers stopped wasting time with issues totally unrelated to the business problems that their applications solve.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but I'm going to stick with Firebase Authentication for this project.

Comment: No worries, I'll leave thinking that I may have helped you in getting a quicker response time from other parties... :)

Comment: To be fair, your competitor's answer here wasn't any more helpful 

Comment: Auth0 may have been an option at one time, but it has morphed into a popup-to-login service which may have improved their ease of use for beginners and very basic apps, but is no good for custom native forms with custom UI. In addition, integration with Firebase Firestore is difficult due to Firebase tokens. Firebase Auth is free whereas Auth0 is paid after a small number of users.

Comment: I would rather roll my own auth service before choosing Auth0, but since Firebase Auth is good enough, just use that.

Comment: How do you migrate users from Auth0 to Firebase Auth? Is there an export feature?

Answer (score 0):

The [Firebase CLI](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) very recently added an [`auth:import`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#auth-commands) command that allows you to import an existing user database into Firebase Auth from CSV or JSON.